# python: is it possible to require that arguments to the functions are all keyword?

Tags: python, function, coding-style, python-3.x

To avoid the obvious bugs, I'd like to prevent the use of positional arguments with some functions. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Why do it? We are all consenting adults here, right?

Comment: The answer is actually really simple: don't. I know, you might think that there is an awesome use case which will solve something brilliantly, but trust me, you are working against the fundamental philosophy of the language -- we are all consenting adults. It will only cause sorrow to pursue such a course.

Comment: This sounds like a silly thing to _enforce_.  However, if you like, you can get into the habit of specifying positional arg by name at function call time.  That way if name of the positional arg changes, callers would get a TypeError (is this the kind of obvious bug you're trying to avoid?).

Comment: It's not that silly to enforce. Some functions are better off with keyword-only args: `list.sort(reverse=True)` is one example. This allows a later version of the API to rearrange the arguments (as Python 3 did). If argument order is not part of the API, code using positional arguments may break if with later versions of the library in question. Such errors should never pass silently.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Only Python 3 can do it properly (and you used the python3 tag, so it's fine):

```
def function(*, x, y, z):
    print(x,y,z)
```

using `**kwargs` will let the user input **any** argument unless you check later. Also, it will hide the real arguments names from introspection.

`**kwargs` is not the answer for this problem.

Testing the program:

```
>>> function(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    function(1,2,3)
TypeError: function() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (3 given)
>>> function(x=1, y=2, z=3)
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 8):

You could define a decorator that, using introspection, causes an error if the function that it decorates uses any positional arguments.  This allows you to prevent the *use* of positional arguments with some functions, while allowing you to *define* those functions as you wish.

As an example:

```
def kwargs_only(f):
    def new_f(**kwargs):
        return f(**kwargs)
    return new_f
```

To use it:

```
@kwargs_only
def abc(a, b, c): return a + b + c
```

You cannot use it thus (type error):

```
abc(1,2,3)
```

You can use it thus:

```
abc(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

A more robust solution would use the `decorator` module.

*Disclaimer: late night answers are not guaranteed!*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the `**kwargs` construct and only read your parameters from there.

```
def my_function(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        print ("%s = %s" % (key, value))

my_function(a="test", b="string")
```

Comment: Hey downvoters: can tell me how this doesn't satisfy the OP's requirements? Exact words: "prevent the use of positional arguments". Nothing else was specified.